# Apex:commandLink - mail to link

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement which is mail to link. In visualforce page I have a commandLink. If I click the link it should open user's default email application (Eg: outlook). How i can achieve this task.

Thanks,
IRaj.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <apex:outputlink value="mailto:{!$user.email}">Email </apex:outputLink>
```